# how to limit tornado websocket message size

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have written a websocket server in tornado and `on_message` method is called when a message is received. The problem is, the message size is unlimited by defualt, In other word, the project is opened to attack by sending a huge data(Message) from a client to the websocket and it makes the server side memory full.  there has to be an option to put a limit on incoming message size, is there? if not, what i have to do to avoid such bug?
**Here is my code to get messages only less than 128 byte length, but it doesn't seem to work.**

```
class ClientWebSocketConnectionHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        print "Connection is opened"

    def on_message(self, message):
        print message

    def on_close(self):
        print "closed"

handlers = [(r'/', ClientWebSocketConnectionHandler)]
tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)
TheShieldsWebSocket = MainApplication()
server =tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(TheShieldsWebSocket,max_body_size=128)
server.listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 4.5 Tornado will close the connection automatically if it receives more than 10 MiB of data in a single websocket frame (message). So, you don't have to worry about someone sending huge data in a single message. You can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.5.3/tornado/websocket.py#L220-L229). It's also mentioned in the docs of [`WebsocketHandler`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler) in the second-last paragraph.

If you'd like to change the default frame limit you can pass your `Application` class an argument called `websocket_max_message_size` with the size in bytes.

```
app = tornado.web.Application(
      # your handlers etc,
      websocket_max_message_size=128
)
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the documentation here:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/http1connection.html#tornado.http1connection.HTTP1Connection.set_max_body_size

To paraphrase for future proofing the link:

> set_max_body_size(max_body_size)[source]
>
> Sets the body size limit for a single request.
>
> Overrides the value from HTTP1ConnectionParameters.

Comment: I just edited my post. could you please put a sample websocket server code that receives limited message length?