# Prevent one websocket connection flooding in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, websocket, tornado, ddos

I use this config for preventing DOS like floodings on my server:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=10r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=sms:10m rate=1r/m;

upstream main_server{
    server web_instance_1:8000;
}

server {
    limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    listen  80;
    server_name something.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  something.com;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;


    location / {
        limit_req zone=one burst=5;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass      https://main_server;
    }

    location /rest/sms {
        limit_req zone=sms burst=5;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass      https://main_server;
    }

    location /WebSocket {
        limit_req zone=one burst=5;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_pass      https://main_server;
    }
}
```

in `/WebSocket` URL I run a WebSocket server (written with Tornado) . `limit_req` in `/WebSocket` location only prevents **too many** websocket connections from client. I need a way to prevent **ONE** WebSocket connection to sends **too many** packets to the server.

current configuration doesn't ban single client that send a lot of packets.

what is the proper way to do so in NGINX or tornado?

Comment: The websocket data is in tcp stream. not transaction. It seems that websocket data can not be separated by packet or transaction. If it is Linux, is it better to use iptables's limit, hashlimit, recent modules. Of course, this is not a packet limit per connection.

Comment: @kangmj37 then you mean there is no way to limit client for this situation? like limit memory usage by any connection or something like that?

Comment: Tornado will automatically close the connection when the client tries to send more than 10 MiB of data in a single websocket message. I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437197/how-to-limit-tornado-websocket-message-size) a while ago.

Comment: @xyres is it handles consecutive tiny packets? or only one huge (10Mib) packet?

Comment: @shotgunner Tornado will keep reading data from a websocket until 10 MiB. The moment it reaches 10 MiB, Tornado will close the connection.