# Rate limiting single websocket connection with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I'm trying to setup rate limiting for a single websocket connection (so that the end user doesn't bomb the connection with `setInterval(_=>socket.send(1))` or stuff like that).

I'm using NodeJS as the backend with nginx as reverse proxy. Sure I can check for websocket bombing on node but I was thinking if nginx could handle this load because it'll keep node free for other tasks. I was not able to find anything regarding single websocket connection limiting with nginx. Is it even possible?

Comment: Some discussion in the comments here, but no answer: [Prevent one websocket connection flooding in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131457/prevent-one-websocket-connection-flooding-in-nginx).

Answer (score 0):

As there is no answer, here is not NGINX solution.

[rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible) package helps.

```
const app = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(app);
const { RateLimiterMemory } = require('rate-limiter-flexible');

app.listen(3000);

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(
  {
    points: 5, // 5 points
    duration: 1, // per second
  });

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('bcast', async (data) => {
    try {
      await rateLimiter.consume(socket.handshake.address); // consume 1 point per event from IP
      socket.emit('news', { 'data': data });
      socket.broadcast.emit('news', { 'data': data });
    } catch(rejRes) {
      // no available points to consume
      // emit error or warning message
      socket.emit('blocked', { 'retry-ms': rejRes.msBeforeNext });
    }
  });
});
```

Read more in [official docs](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#websocket-single-connection-prevent-flooding)