# Increase max_buffer_size limit of BaseIOStream in Tornado

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, large-files

Tornado websocket server is used for bidirectional communication with clients where large payloads may be sent. I have already increased the size of the socket message using:

```
tornado.web.Application(tuples, websocket_max_message_size = 256 * 1024 * 1024),
```

according to:[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437197/how-to-limit-tornado-websocket-message-size). However, I get an exception if the message exceeds 100MiB (Read buffer size exceeded).

Tried:
I believe I have traced that exception in [BaseIoStream](https://kite.com/python/docs/tornado.iostream.BaseIOStream) where *max_buffer_size* is set to 100MiB value. How can I increase that buffer size as well (or anything else, so I can receive messages > 100MiB) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the IOStream's buffer limit from your `WebSocketHandler` subclass like this:

```
class YourWebSocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request.connection.stream.max_buffer_size = 256 * 1024 * 1024
```

This also works for `RequestHandler` subclasses.